# All-ukrainian math Olympiad task

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Prove that for any natural numbers a and b,  max(a,b)>1, there are infinitely many natural n, such that the number $S(n)=a^n+b^{n+1}$ would be composite.
Contest web page: https://matholymp.com.ua

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I would rather say that you should provide some *context* as described in [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). In the case of a contest question you could give us the link to the contest web page. This is important also for the reason that we have a strict policy not to answer questions from *on-going* contests.

Comment: I've already  left the link under the problem's condition.

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ and $b$ have some common factor then this factor always divides $a^n + b^{n+1}$ which immediately yields the required result.

Otherwise, $\gcd (a,b) = 1$. Take any prime factor $p$ of $a+b^2$. Clearly $p$ cannot divide $a$ or $b$, because if it did it would have to divide the other (due to $p \mid a+b^2$), contradicting the fact that’s $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

By Fermat’s little theorem, $a^{p-1} \equiv b^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. So if we let $n = k(p-1)+1$, we immediately obtain $a^n + b^{n+1} \equiv a+b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$, and so $p$ divides $a^n + b^{n+1}$. But since this is clearly greater than $a+b^2$ for all positive $k$, it is composite, and so since all $k$ work we obtain infinitely many composites, as required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear solution, the official solution of the jury was a bit overcomplicated, but had the same idea.